# Nested ng-repeat tbody different list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My code is something like this:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in ctrl.list">
  <tr>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{item.numerodoc}}<br>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{item.sgmittragsoc}}<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-if="toggle[$index]" ng-repeat="detail in ctrl.details">
     <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{detail.sgmittragsoc}}<br>
     </td>
     <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{detail.sgdestragsoc}}<br>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The first part is working (I'm able to repeat every item in the list), the second part is not working (I'm unable to repeat every item on the details list).
That tr  will activate only when I click a button and the details list will change.
What should I do to make it work?
I cannot use a div inside the tbody and I even tried the ng-repeat-start but I was not able to understand where to put the ng-repeat-end since I only have a tr to repeat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the ng-repeat-start / -end structure.
I am unable to test this as I am missing most of you code, but the start/end works like this.
Also, you want to place the ng-repeat on `<tr>` because you do not want to repeat the whole table.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="item in ctrl.list">
    <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{item.numerodoc}}<br>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{item.sgmittragsoc}}<br>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end>
     <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{detail.sgmittragsoc}}<br>
     </td>
     <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{detail.sgdestragsoc}}<br>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also, how is the structure of your arrays?
Are the lists and details in the same scope?
It really depends. Give me some more details and I might be able to help!

Comment: Yes list and details are in the same scope. The main problem was that I wanted to get 1 generic list of item (from list) and 1 detail list (from details) that will change based on the selected item on the generic list. I'm not sure how to explain it better than this.... but I have 1 list of object that I visualize with an ng-repeat and, when a click a button of a specific item of that list it will call a backend service to get a list based on id of that object and that service will return a list of items that I want to visualize in another ng-repeat inside my ng-repeat, the new list can change

Comment: Still, I'm ok with my current solution. The main thing that I would like to change now is not the ng-repeat but the fact that I cannot open more than 1 details because since my details list update and change and my ng-repeat always use details it will also update my previous details. Right now is not an official request from my company so I can ignore it but I'm afraid they will request it soon.

Comment: I am not sure you can do that since the way you access data is through the response object.

Comment: Unless you want to make multiple async calls and repeat the data from two responses

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a strange but working way:

```
<tr ng-if="toggle[$index]">
 <td>
    <table class="table borderless" style="margin: 10px 0;">
        <tbody ng-repeat="detail in ctrl.details">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </td>
 <td>
    <table class="table borderless" style="margin: 10px 0;">
        <tbody ng-repeat="detail in ctrl.details">
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </td>
 <td>
    <table class="table borderless" style="margin: 10px 0;">
        <tbody ng-repeat="detail in ctrl.details">
            <tr>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle">{{detail.sgmittragsoc}}<br>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </td>
</tr>
```

I have to repeat the table every time to get the correct layout on my webapp but the main focus is that you can loop ng-repeat inside an ng-repeat body by using a table inside a td tag.

Comment: This looks a little weird. Could you please add the code to some online editor and send the link?

Comment: @MaksymBezruchko I'm sorry but I cannot do something like that. The complete code is something that belong to the company I'm working for, I don't have the right to share it.